# IE8 Compatible Timer Directive

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8, angularjs-directive

I'm working on an Angular directive that is IE8 compatible. Here is what I've got so far. It works in Chrome, of course, but I can't get this code to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>NG Directive</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var TimerApp = angular.module('TimerApp', []);
        TimerApp.directive('timer', function($interval){
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                replace: 'true',
                link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
                    scope.seconds = 0;
                    scope.minutes = 0;

                    $interval(function(){
                        scope.seconds++;
                        if(scope.seconds > 59) {
                            scope.seconds = 0;
                            scope.minutes++;
                        }
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="TimerApp">
    <timer>Seconds: {{seconds}} Minutes: {{minutes}}</timer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 does not like custom tags, take a look at this [post](http://www.befundoo.com/blog/angularjs-directives-in-ie8/) for more info. You can either take that advice or allow your directive to work on Attribute or Class.

Comment: Glad it worked for you, an up-vote would be appreciated.

Comment: I have to have a 15 rep. I'm sorry. I will when I get there.

Comment: Ah yes, site restrictions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got ie9. i tested your code on ie8 browser and document mode selected from developer tools and seems to work. You would get a message like this "internet explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts for Active x" click Enable blocked content and should work.